# Need a Perl script to match a string in all files inside a directory and push matching ones to new folder

Tags: perl, shell

I want a Perl script to search in the mentioned directory and find those files 
which contains the string `ADMITTING DX` and push those files to a new folder.

I am new to Perl and was trying this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Find;

my $dir    = '/usr/share/uci_cmc/uci_new_files/';
my $string = 'ADMITTING DX';

open my $results, '>', '/home/debarshi/Desktop/results.txt'
    or die "Unable to open results file: $!";

find(\&printFile, $dir);

sub printFile {

    return unless -f and /\.txt$/;

    open my $fh, '<',, $_ or do {
        warn qq(Unable to open "$File::Find::name" for reading: $!);
        return;
    };

    while ($fh) {
        if (/\Q$string/) {
            print $results "$File::Find::name\n";
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you need to recurse into deeper nested directories, or do you just want the ones in a single flat directory?

Answer (score 2):

You are reading the lines from the file as:

```
while ($fh)
```

which should be

```
while (<$fh>)
```

Comment: Tried with your suggestion but did not work out. Please suggest.

Comment: @user1679829: You must explain better what you mean by *did not work out*

Answer (score 1):

You can really do it with Perl and that's a great way. But there's no any complex text processing in your case so I'd just advise using bash one-liner:

```
for f in *.txt; do grep 'ADMITTING DX' $f >/dev/null && mv $f /path/to/destination/; done
```

Comment: Tried but to no avail. Do I need to put it in a script or so. It would be helpful if u can take the pain to elaborate.

Comment: just open a terminal, `cd` to the directory where your input files are located and copy-paste the code to the command line (don't forget to change `/path/to/destination/` to the location of the existing directory where you want your output files).

Answer (score 0):

And if you still need a Perl solution:

```
perl -e 'for my $f (glob "*.txt") { open F, $f or die $!; while(<F>){ if(/ADMITTING DX/){ rename $f, "/path/to/destination/$f" or die $!; last } close $f; }}'
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors in your code. Firstly you have a superfluous comma in the `open` call in `printFile`. It should read

```
open my $fh, '<', $_ or do { ... };
```

and secondly you need a call to `readline` to fetch data from the opened file. You can do this with `<$fh>`, so the `while` loop should read

```
while (<$fh>) { ... }
```

Apart from that your code is fine